# Unable to install Skype on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, skype

After installation I am getting like this:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/s/skype/skype_4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]   
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: few guys did some comments on how to install skype but those are not working

Comment: Just download it from the official web site and install it, after you finish installing it you will see that it is Skype Beta, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The legacy Skype for Linux application (v4.*) that was included in the repositories and partner repositories has been retired as of 1 July 2017. You can however still use the web-based [Skype for Linux](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/) application.

Comment: According to the link "Important notice: All Skype for Linux clients version 4.3 and older will be retired on July 1, 2017. To keep chatting, please install the latest version of Skype for Linux." It seems it still is a client (beta version) and not a web based app.

Comment: I'm using it on `16.04` as beta version and it's working properly.

Comment: @suraj It **IS** a web-based app, using WebRTC and electron.

Comment: @pomsky ok.. but the answer does seem to be misleading when it says the official app is retired.. It is really the older version which is retired

Comment: @pomsky Usually when people say "web-based app" they mean a webapp that's used by opening a general-purpose web browser such as Firefox and navigating to a page. The wording of this answer strongly suggests this was the intended meaning, since it says "you can still use" (emphasis mine), and the app whose download page you've linked to--which is also now the official Skype for Linux!--is a much more recent development than the version of Skype the OP was trying to install from the Partner repository. I'm reluctant to roll your edits back, but they really should've been a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

following steps worked out for me:

1) Download deb package of *skype* from source (`I'm taking from https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb`)

2) Install *GDebi package Installer* from ubuntu software center or from command line.

3) Install the downloaded deb package of *skype* with *GDebi package Installer*.

Note: you can also try with `dpkg -i <deb-package>` but sometimes it stucks in resolving dependencies so I prefer to go with *GDebi package Installer*.